# Search results are very slow when retrieving Varchar Records using like operator

Tags: sql-server-2005

Email Match field = '@hotmail.com'

Email Match field entered: Results 1199 - speed of return 40 seconds

Email Match field not entered: Results 429 - speed of return 1.6 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM emails e where e.[From] like '%@hotmail.com%' OR e.[To] like '%@hotmail.com%'order by [id] DESC
```

I have to use % at start and end because i want to search this in email addresses

Edit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Execution plan of original query

Comment: How many rows do you have? Do you have indexes in the field?

Comment: Yes i am using indexes but i guess when % sign is used at start and end of search field indexes are ignored ?

Answer (score 1):

Indexing and statistics is always the first thing you want to look at when optimizing performance, but for a more general approach targeting that exact query:

The `OR` clause will actually divide the query into two queries, one checking for each criteria, execute both, and then merge the results and filter out duplicates.

You might gain performance by a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM emails e
WHERE (e.From + '/' + e.To) LIKE '%@hotmail.com%'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

... although it's a bit uglier =) Try it out in your query analyzer and see what performs best...

**EDIT**

As Martin pointed out in comments, if the fields are nullable, the `WHERE` clause should have to be updated to accommodate that:

```
WHERE ( ISNULL(e.From,'') + '/' + ISNULL(e.To,'') ) LIKE '%@hotmail.com%'
```

Comment: I doubt this bit about the `or` clause will be true. It will just do a single clustered index scan. The query returns all columns anyway.

Comment: Yes this took half time to load result i have about 438605 records in table

Comment: @user467710 What do the execution plans look like for the 2 versions? And what is the structure of your table and indexes? Remember to take account that concatenating NULL yields NULL so this query will need adjustment.

Comment: @Martin: Ah, ISNULL padding in case of nullable fiels is a very valid point! (although it might not make much sense for an `emails` table to have either of those fields nullable -- or perhaps for drafts? -- i have edited the answer accordingly)

Comment: @David +1 but @user467710 I'm still interested in what the execution plans look like.

Comment: I am not able to upload execution plan image/files because i don't have enough points.

Comment: If you could screenshot the execution plan before and after the change, and upload to something like http://imgur.com/ and paste the links in a comment here, that would still be useful to us :)

Comment: I have added images for execution plan.

Comment: Search results are again slow because in table records keeps on adding.